# How to create a (recurring) Google Calendar Out of Office Event?

Tags: google-calendar

I’m going through the Google Calendar API, and I can’t find a way to mark an event as "Out of Office".

I work from home every Thursday — and by default in the Google Calendar one cannot make OOO events recurring, so I'd like to do it via scripting.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could consider IFTT or a chrome extension. I have the same need to let you know if I figure something out!

Comment: The feature you are looking for was missing but is **coming soon**, according to the [Google Workspace Updates blog](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/02/create-repeating-ooo-entries-and-segment-working-hours-in-google-calendar.html).

Answer (score 2):

The feature mentioned by torzmokus is available now.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might not be directly what you're looking for, but maybe it's a useful alternative: you can set working hours in the settings of the web interface of Gmail calendar, this apparently will warn others if they try to schedule you into something out of those hours:

> Working Hours
>
> Enable working hours to let people know what times
>   you're working and when you're available for meetings. This will warn
>   people if they try to invite you to a meeting outside of these hours.
>   Enable working hours

Comment: Good suggestion - unfortunately, there's a big difference. OOO automatically blocks meetings and shows up on the view of the calendar, which is nice you have a very restrictive or complex schedule like me. Working hours only warns the meeting creator and only after they try to create the event. I don't know there's any way to see someone's working hours before scheduling.

Comment: Also, working hours only allows a single start and end time per day, so it's not helpful to make a scheduled out-of-office time in the middle of the day.

Comment: @combinatorist when you use the _Find a time_ feature, it shows the working hours of everyone added to the event (to be precise, the non-working hours are shown with a striped background)